# Excel 2013 create column w/specific value from another column?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a column "application url" (this is a feed
from Apple). Within that column/url is the id number of the product:

> http://itunes.apple.com/app/pntool/id852499288?uo=5

The above is a standard example of the data in the column "application url".

What I'd like to do is create a new column A (moving the existing column "a" to column "b", "b" to "c", etc…) titled "ID" and populate it with just the
id number (the number following "id" but preceeding the "?").

So that I end up with:

> Column A
>
> ID
>
> 777888999

And, of course, each row's ID would match that with the id found in that
row's "application url" column.

Comment: SO is a site for questions about programming.  Voting to close.

Comment: Excel worksheet functions are a form of programming, and are permitted on the site, but I'll warn the author that he should do more research in the future before posting a question like this, as he will just risk downvoting and closure.  This site is to help with specific programming issues that programmers have, and is not just a 'gimme the codez' site.  You need to show us what you have tried and what is not working.  For very basic excel worksheet function questions go to [SU].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If B will be new column that the url is in, then use the following formula in A, and drag down.

```
=MID(B2, SEARCH("id",B2)+2, SEARCH("~?",B2)-SEARCH("id",B2)-2)
```

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for the help and the info. I appreciate what you wrote - my problem in researching stemmed more from how to phrase what I was looking for than lack of trying…but your solution looks like what I've used in the past. So this is "very basic"? I must just be getting old! Thanks again and I will utilize Super user moving forward.